# why when I am logged in I cannot go to "all questions"

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

When I try to get "All Questions" at https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions I get only the ones with a bonus flag. I use firefox and am logged in. With Chrome and IE  not logged in the same link gives all questions.  I logged in at IE and got again only the bounty questions!

Whats up?

Answer (score 5):

There is a bar like this just below the header:

[image]

you are likely on the featured tab. Change it to active to get the default filter.

Comment: thanks, that did it